# Submit form for php without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've search for many solution but without success.

I have a **html form**;

```
<form id="objectsForm" method="POST">
      <input type="submit" name="objectsButton" id="objectsButton">
</form>
```

This is used for a menu button.

I'm using **jquery** to prevent the site from refreshing;

```
$('#objectsForm').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/php/objects.php',
        data: $('#objectsForm').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        }
    });

});
```

In my **php file** I try to echo text to the body of my site;

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["objectsButton"])){
     echo '<div id="success"><p>objects</p></div>';
} else {
echo '<div id="fail"><p>nope</p></div>';
}
?>
```

I know the path to my php file is correct, but it doesn't show anything? Not even the "fail div".
Does anyone has a solution for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the given php code in the /php/objects.php file?

Comment: Yes it is.. Maybe it has something to do that i don't include the php file?

Comment: If it's in a different file, the server output won't appear on the page. You have to use success callback function to specify what you want to do with the server's response data.

Comment: That means when you do the ajax call, your browser requests that page in the background and gets the result back with the success function as the first parameter. The code is not inserted automatically to your body. you have to do that manually. Use `success: function (data) {$('body').append(data);} or Touch Cats answer.

Comment: Yes that was it! Thx for the reply.

It does alert: <div id="fail"><p>nope</p></div> Any idea why it doesn't alert: <div id="success"><p>objects</p></div>? Why is "objectsButton" not posted?

Comment: Because the serialization of you form is an empty string, see this http://jsfiddle.net/f517a2k5/ . You could do `data: {objectsButton: 'some unimportant value'}` if you want to set this post variable.

Comment: Assuming you somewhere do a `$('#objectsButton').val("Objecten");` like you said in another comment, you could also do: `data: {objectsButton: $('#objectsButton').val()}`, if that value is somehow important in you php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The success function takes two parameters. The first parameter is what is returned from the php file. Try changing it to:

> success: function (xhr){ alert(xhr);}

Comment: Ah I was using it the wrong way! Thx.
I does alert: <div id="fail"><p>nope</p></div>
Any idea why it doesn't alert: <div id="success"><p>objects</p></div>? Why is "objectsButton" not posted?

Comment: objectsButton doesn't have a value attribute. E.g.: <input type="submit" name="objectsButton" id="objectsButton" value="test">

Comment: It does have a value attribute. I'm giving the value attribute trought jquery: $('#objectsButton').val("Objecten");
Sorry for not showing.

Comment: But you prevent the submit button from doing it's job by calling e.preventDefault(), this also prevents *sending* that button value.

Comment: Ah ok! Is there anyway I can send the button value but not refresh the page?

Answer (score 1):

PHP scripts run on the server, that means any echo you do won't appear at the user's end.

Instead of echoing the html just echo a json encoded success/ failure flag e.g. 0 or 1.

You'll be able to get that value in your success function and use jQuery to place divs on the web page.

PHP:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["objectsButton"])){
         echo json_encode(1); // for success
    } else {
        echo json_encode(0); // for failure
    }
?>
```

jQuery:

```
var formData = $('#objectsForm').serializeArray();
formData.push({name:this.name, value:this.value });

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/php/objects.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: formData,
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == 1) {
            alert('success');
        } else {
            alert('fail');
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

To include the button, try using the following (just before the `$.ajax` block, **see above**):

```
formData.push({name:this.name, value:this.value });
```

Also, have the value attribute for your button:

```
<input type="submit" name="objectsButton" value="objectsButton" id="objectsButton">
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. Got it working , except for the Post part in the php file. Any idea why it does alert "fail" instead of "success"? It seems that $POST["objectsButton"] is false...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. But it says: formData is not defined. I tried to succees using: var formData = new.FormData(); but that will give the following result: "undefined". Any idea?

Comment: See the jQuery section above. Note the change in the ajax block for the data.

Answer (score 1):

Based in your php source..

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "html", // Receive html content
    url: '/php/objects.php',
    data: $('#objectsForm').serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        $('#divResult').html(result);
    }
});
```